# Append SQL to SQLite .dump

Tags: windows, sqlite, shell

Is there a way to get sqlite to output additional SQL to drop database if exist upon execution of .dump?

One option I thought of is if I could manually append the "drop database if exist" somehow when the .dump command is executed. However, I'm not familar with windows shell scripting and would appreciate some advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
.output dump.sql
SELECT 'DROP DATABASE IF EXIST ...';
.dump
.output stdout
```

Comment: Using a literal is a good idea. Unfortunately, DROP DATABASE is not supported by SQLite.